# CA - How to get the frequency of the applied rules at a certain timestep in Wolfram Language

Tags: cellular-automata

From an CA `CellularAutomaton[110, {{1},0}, 64]` how can I get the frequency of the applied rules at a row/timestep?

Meaning, the number of times a rule/subrule has been applied to create a row.

Comment: What do you mean by: " frequency of the applied rules at a row/timestep"? Note, every point inside the triangle  (with the exception of the first point) is the result of an application of the rule.

Comment: The number of times a rule (subrule) has been applied in the creation of a row

Comment: Every point in a row of the triangle is one application.

Comment: Yes, each point coming from one of f.i. 8 rules

Comment: The absolute frequency of a rule per timestep, f.i.: 'rule 3 has been applied 20 times', or 20 of 100 total rule applications (the relative frequency then).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule that will be applied for each cell is determined by its value and the value of its two nearest neighbors, The value of these three cells is a 3 digit binary number which is applied to the rule lookup table which in your example is rule 110. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110 for more details.

In your example you are executing rule 110 for 64 steps.

Lets give this output a name:

`r110 = CellularAutomaton[110, {{1}, 0}, 64]`
where `r110[[n]]` is the nth row of the output.

The rules that will be applied to each cell is the binary number made from itself and its neighbors at each point in time.

For each row of the output we can get a list of the rules that will be applied to each cell with:

`Partition[r110[[1]], 3, 1]`

We can convert these into decimal rule numbers with:

`FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ Partition[r110[[1]], 3, 1]`

Putting the pieces together we can have:

```
bRules = Partition[#, 3, 1] & /@ r110
dRules = Map[FromDigits[#, 2] &, bRules, {2}]
```

Which gives us a list of what rule is applied to each cell to get its value for the next row.

We can add up the number of times each rule is applied in a given step:

```
ruleCounts = BinCounts[#, {0, 8, 1}] & /@ dRules
```

A useful way to display this might be a stacked list plot.

```
StackedListPlot[Transpose[ruleCounts], PlotLegends -> Range[0, 8], 
 Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}},  
 FrameLabel -> {{"Occurrences of Rule", None}, {"Iteration", None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot!